# SQL Server: cannot access system tables

Tags: sql-server, system-tables

I have an MSSQL database and a "normal" user accessing it. When I try to use tables like sys.objects, I become a permission error:

```
select name from sys.objects
Msg 229, Level 14, State 5, Line 1
The SELECT permission was denied on the object 'objects', database 'mssqlsystemresource', schema 'sys'.
```

Why? The documentation says

> In SQL Server 2005 and later versions, the visibility of the metadata
>   in catalog views is limited to securables that a user either owns or
>   on which the user has been granted some permission.

so I think I should be allowed to use sys.objects, even if it will list only the for me visible objects...

My user have been created with

```
CREATE LOGIN [factoryFX20_K_user] WITH PASSWORD=N'...', DEFAULT_DATABASE=[ff20121025], DEFAULT_LANGUAGE=[English], CHECK_EXPIRATION=OFF, CHECK_POLICY=ON
EXEC sys.sp_addsrvrolemember @loginame = N'factoryFX20_K_user', @rolename = N'serveradmin'

USE [ff20121025]
CREATE USER [factoryFX20_K_user] FOR LOGIN [factoryFX20_K_user] WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA=[factoryFX20_K_user]
```

Comment: Is it possible someone might have added extra security on `sys.objects`  on your box. Can you test on a different server?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have another 10.0 Server. And I cannot find any customizing in the security of sys.objects.

Comment: possible duplicate of [The SELECT permission was denied on the object 'sysobjects', database 'mssqlsystemresource', schema 'sys'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1473315/the-select-permission-was-denied-on-the-object-sysobjects-database-mssqlsyst)

Comment: You're right: same problem and solution as the link you've found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was ideed the same as in [The SELECT permission was denied on the object 'sysobjects', database 'mssqlsystemresource', schema 'sys'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1473315/the-select-permission-was-denied-on-the-object-sysobjects-database-mssqlsyst): my user had some "denying" roles.

The solution was to remove this roles of the user:

```
USE [ff20121025]
EXEC sp_droprolemember N'db_denydatawriter', N'factoryFX20_K_user'
EXEC sp_droprolemember N'db_denydatareader', N'factoryFX20_K_user'
```

Thanks Jon!