# SQL Server Management Studio The SELECT permission was denied

Tags: sql, sql-server

In Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio, I unchecked 'sysadmin' for my Windows user under server roles in Security -> Logins. Now when I try to connect to SQL Server using Windows authentication, I get the error

> The SELECT permission was denied on the object 'configurations',  database 'mssqlsystemresource', schema 'sys'.  (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 229).

Please help!

Comment: Check if your Windows user has any explicit 'Deny' privileges set.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The SELECT permission was denied on the object 'sysobjects', database 'mssqlsystemresource', schema 'sys'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1473315/the-select-permission-was-denied-on-the-object-sysobjects-database-mssqlsyst)

Comment: @GoatCO I can't get into management studio at all. All the privileges are set except sysadmin, including all the deny privileges.