# Unable to select sys.tables on SQL Server on AWS RDS

Tags: sql-server, knex.js, rds, tedious

I'm currently getting the error:

```
RequestError: The SELECT permission was denied on the object 'tables', database 'mssqlsystemresource', schema 'sys'.
```

This is from running a migration with knex.js; we've just recently switched our local database instance over to RDS and are now running into this.

The user that knex.js is using is the master/admin user that is setup when configuring RDS; I would expect it to have full permissions.

Is this just something that AWS RDS does not allow? Seems a bit ridiculous.

Comment: This could help if not AWS specific https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1473315/the-select-permission-was-denied-on-the-object-sysobjects-database-mssqlsyst

Comment: AWS restricts your permissions to different administrative and Sysadmin accesses, system tables, and (apparently) the hidden `mssqlsystemresource` database. That isn't much of a surprise when you think about it.

Comment: @LaughingVergil I was aware that some administrative access would be restricted; and read that in various parts of their documentation - but they never listed anything specific. Quite frustrating since the application and everything works - just not our migrations.